# FPGA (VHDL) - LED blinks upon receiving Ethernet packets

Tags: vhdl

I'm using an FPGA board which is connected with a Linux-server box which is used for Ethernet packet transmission. Upon receiving every 10 packets one LED should blink once and the process will continue. That means if I'll send 100 packets the LED should blink 10 times. I've shared the VHDL source code which I tried to run but it's not working the way I want.Any help or suggestion will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```css
---------------------------------------------



library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;

use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;



---------------------------------------------



entity notification is 

port (clk: in std_logic;

      reset: in std_logic;

      dv: in std_logic;

      LED: out std_logic

   );

end notification;

   

architecture behavior of notification is

   

signal packet_count: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

signal q: std_logic;



begin

process(clk)



begin

if reset = '1' then

 packet_count <= "0000";

elsif dv = '1' then

  if packet_count < "1010" then

     packet_count <= packet_count + 1;

     q <= '0';

  else 

     q <= '1';

     packet_count <= (others => '0');

  end if;

end if;



LED <= q;



end process;

end behavior;
```

Comment: There's no (rising_edge) clock if-statement in your code. Look up synchronous design in VHDL.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains several mistakes that I explain below. You might want to consider reading some more basic VHDL literature and do tutorials, like [this one](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/tutorials/tutorial-introduction-to-vhdl-for-beginners.html).

First of all: Your process does not contain any timing code. You should make it clock synchronous by making your process look like this:

```
notification: process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
          --<the code you already had>
    end if;
end process;
```

If you want to keep the reset asynchronous(that might not be a good idea, read more [here](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.de/2010/04/synchronous-vs-asynchronous-resets-in.html)) you can change that to

```
notification: process(clk)
begin
    if reset = '1' then
          --<your reset conditions here>
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
          --<the code you already had>
    end if;
end process;
```

Another issue with your code is the usage of `ieee.std_logic_arith` and `ieee.std_logic_unsigned`. **These libraries are deprecated**. Unlike what their name suggests, they are not standard IEEE libraries and you definitely should not use them. Instead, you should use `ieee.numeric_std.all`(more [here](http://insights.sigasi.com/tech/deprecated-ieee-libraries.html))

However, your code does not require use of `ieee.numeric_std` at all. You can(and probably should for better readability) declare your `packet_count` as `integer` and compare it to an integer value, i.e.

```
signal packet_count : integer range 0 to 10;
notification: process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
         -- <all your other stuff>
         if packet_count = 10 then
             -- <whatever you want to do
         end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Integers used to be a problem for synthesis tools, but that's years and years ago. These days, you can and should use integers for things like counters.

Comment: Please have a look below.

Comment: Have a look below what?